# How to make jquery UI Tabs + Google Maps for ExpressionEngine play nice together

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-for-ee

Anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Here's my live [test example](http://vibe9design.com/dev/map_test.html).

My example demonstrates Google Maps (almost) in action within jQuery UI tabs. Notice that the maps don't fully initialize in each tab. I know there's [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344059/how-to-add-google-maps-in-two-tabs-of-jquery-application/7029514#7029514) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067993/jquery-ui-tabs-and-google-maps-v3-resizemap) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428178/problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs/3066751#3066751) on [this issue](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/6/5/jQuery-Tabs-and-Google-Maps) out there, but none of them apply to the way Google Maps for EE does it's thing with Google Maps API v3.

Any help would be forever and greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: I had to do the same sort of thing at one point, and got it working with Justin Kimbrell's help (@objectivehtml). It was a while ago now, but I seem to recall him having me add a click event listener within one of the Google Maps add-on files.  It meant that the mapping would initialize when the nearest parent click event (in my case an accordion hide/reveal) was clicked.

Comment: Should be pretty easy. From jQuery UI docs:  http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate Bind an event listener to the tabsload event:
$( ".selector" ).on( "tabsload", function( event, ui ) {} );

Comment: Thanks guys, my head is spinning already!  Jean, any chance you have the code that you had to add in?

Comment: Just as a tip I wouldn't try to load ALL maps at once. The page loading time is crazy long. Heavy widgets like Google Maps and social widgets are notorious in adding huge weight to a page so just load each one on request as Jean suggests. Binding an event handler to each tab to make the call.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is answered here I believe: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3066751/135935

I recently fixed the same problem by changing my CSS to use the off-left positioning suggested in the answer. Worked perfectly.

> Use the off-left technique for hiding inactive tab panels. E.g. in
>   your style sheet replace the rule for the class selector ".ui-tabs
>   .ui-tabs-hide" with
>
> .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
>       position: absolute;
>       left: -10000px; }

Comment: Stuck on a couple other projects at the moment Anna, but will be returning to this problem soon enough. Thanks for the input!